# How to give different colors when I loop for plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some data say X with size (100,2). This X is composed of data for 10 categories (set of 10). Now I would like to look the pattern in the data for each category. For this I need to have different colors assigned to each category. I am trying to loop instead of doing 10 different plots. I tried the below.

```
hold on
for i=1:10:100
   plot(X(i:i+9,1),X(i:i+9,2),'.')
end
hold off
```

This gave me a plot with same color. How can I assign different colors for different range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to replace `hold on` by `hold all`.

If you want more control you have to manually define your line specifications (more info [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)) and then pass them to `plot`:

```
linespec = {'b.', 'r-', 'g--o'}; % define your ten linespecs in a cell array
hold on
for i=1:10:100
   plot(X(i:i+9,1),X(i:i+9,2),linespec{i})
end
hold off
```

Answer (score 8):

The answers mentioning `hold all` are correct and useful for cycling through the colors specified by the [`ColorOrder` `axes` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#ColorOrder) (even though just `hold on` is now equivalent to `hold all`). However, by default MATLAB only specifies a short list of colors (just 7 as of R2013b) to cycle through, and on the other hand it can be problematic to find a good set of colors for more data series. For 10 plots, you obviously cannot rely on the default `ColorOrder`, so a great way to **define N visually distinct colors** is with the ["Generate Maximally Perceptually-Distinct Colors" (GMPDC) submission on the MATLAB Central File File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors).  It is best described in the author's own words:

> This function generates a set of colors which are distinguishable by reference to the "Lab" color space, which more closely matches human color perception than RGB. Given an initial large list of possible colors, it iteratively chooses the entry in the list that is farthest (in Lab space) from all previously-chosen entries.

For example, here are the colors generated when 25 are requested:

[image: 25 "maximally perceptually-distinct colors"]

The GMPDC submission was chosen on MathWorks' official blog as [Pick of the Week a few years ago](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/12/23/generate-distinct-colors-for-your-matlab-plots/) in part because of the ability to request an arbitrary number of colors (in contrast to MATLAB's built in 7 default colors).  They even made the excellent suggestion to set MATLAB's `ColorOrder` on startup to,

```
distinguishable_colors(20)
```

Of course, you can set the `ColorOrder` for a single axis or simply generate a list of colors to use in any way you like.  For example, to generate 10 "maximally perceptually-distinct colors" and use them for 10 plots on the same axis (not using `ColorOrder`):

```
% Starting with X of size 100x2
X = reshape(X,10,10,2); % for clarity, column is category, row is observation
mpdc10 = distinguishable_colors(10) % 10x3 color list
hold on
for ii=1:10,
    plot(X(:,ii,1),X(:,ii,2),'.','Color',mpdc10(ii,:));
end
```

Alternatively, using the `ColorOrder` axis property simplifies the process:

```
X = reshape(X,10,10,2); % for clarity, and to avoid loop
mpdc10 = distinguishable_colors(10) % 10x3 color map
ha = axes; hold(ha,'on')
set(ha,'ColorOrder',mpdc10)
plot(X(:,:,1),X(:,:,2),'-.') % loop NOT needed, 'Color' NOT needed
```

**APPENDIX**

To get the `ColorOrder` RGB array used for the current axis,

```
get(gca,'ColorOrder')
```

To get the default `ColorOrder` for new axes,

```
get(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder')
```

Example of setting new global `ColorOrder` with 10 colors on MATLAB start, in `startup.m`:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',distinguishable_colors(10))
```

Comment: `ha = axes; hold(ha,'on')` did not work well on Matlab 2016b. It produced broken axis ticks, when plotting many plots in one figure. `ha = gca;` worked

Comment: @JonasStein `axes` just creates new axes, while `gca` gets the current axes or creates new axes if none are open.  So if it doesn't work anymore, that's worth reporting to MathWorks.  However, I'm running R2016b and I don't observe any problems.  Can you post a gist to reproduce?  And/or a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

`hold on` makes sure the new `plot` command adds to the plot instead of replacing it. However, each command works as if it were generating a fresh plot, including starting with the first line color (blue). If you want subsequent plots use different colors, use `hold all` instead. That way the standard 7 line colors are used in turn.

Since you have 10 lines to plot, you might want to specify the colors explicitly to make sure they are all different. For that, use the syntax

```
plot(..., 'Color', [r g b])
```

Comment: Oh, great. Once more, The Mathworks in their infinite wisdom decided to break compatibility... >:( No idea how they get away with this behavior.

Comment: Because they are better than any of the options.  Ever hear of MatrixX? Precisely.