# Matlab animation loop

Tags: matlab, loops, animation

I have the following loop to produce an animation:

```
for ii=1:5:length(Coors)-5
    for jj=1:6

        plot(Coors(ii,1),Coors(ii,2),'o','color',cc(ii,:),'MarkerSize',jj)
        plot(Coors(ii+1,1),Coors(ii+1,2),'o','color',cc(ii+1,:),'MarkerSize',jj)
        plot(Coors(ii+2,1),Coors(ii+2,2),'o','color',cc(ii+2,:),'MarkerSize',jj)
        plot(Coors(ii+3,1),Coors(ii+3,2),'o','color',cc(ii+3,:),'MarkerSize',jj)
        plot(Coors(ii+4,1),Coors(ii+4,2),'o','color',cc(ii+4,:),'MarkerSize',jj)

        drawnow

        frame = getframe;
        writeVideo(writerObj,frame);


    end

end
```

This plots a batch of five points (ii in steps of 5) simultaneously marking them with growing circles (jj from 1 to 6) and it works well.

What I want now is to have the whole thing growing one point at the time, one size a the time until they reach the dessired size, this is:

Frame one: point 1->size 1

Frame two: point 1->size 2, point 2->size 1

...

Frame five: point 1->size 5, point 2->size 4, point 3-> size 3 ...

Frame six: point 6->size 1, point 2->size 5,...

can anyone think of an elegant way to do this without many many loops and ifs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here comes a simplified solutions which just draws 6 points and stores the plot handle for each point. The handles are used to adjust the MarkerSize of the points by 1 in each iteration. You can then adapt this code for your case.

```
Coors = rand(6,2); % random coordinates
figure
axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
hold on

handles = []; % vector to store plot handles in
for ii=1:6
    handle = plot(Coors(ii,1),Coors(ii,2),'ko','MarkerfaceColor', 'black', 'MarkerSize',1);

    % adjust handles
    for h = 1:length(handles)
        set(handles(h), 'markersize', get(handles(h), 'markersize') + 1); % increment markersize by 1
    end

    % add new handle to handles vector
    handles = [handles, handle];

    % draw now
    pause(1)

end
```

Reading the MarkerSize property in the end yields the desired MarkerSizes

```
get(handles, 'markersize')

ans = 

    [6]
    [5]
    [4]
    [3]
    [2]
    [1]
```

Comment: Great idea, din't knew you can change that over the handle properties! Works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you -

```
ha = axes; %/// handle to current axes
for ii=1:5:length(Coors)-5
    set(ha,'ColorOrder',cc(ii:ii+4,:)) %// <--- Most important stuff of this approach
    for jj=1:6

        %//Use array of XY instead of individual points; thus saving on many loops
        plot(Coors(ii:ii+4,1),Coors(ii:ii+4,2),'o','MarkerSize',jj) 
        drawnow

        frame = getframe;
        writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
    end
end
```

This approach uses `'ColorOrder'` with `axes` to use a matrix of colors and thus works in one go.

Based on this nice solution - [How to give different colors when I loop for plot in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354045/3293881)

Comment: @McMa Added link to original source.